# Is making memory readable, writeable and executeable subject to any performance impact?

Tags: c++, optimization, vm-implementation

I am writing virtual machine that has Garbage Collector that when he runs out of memory he allocates big chunk of memory. I need to implement delegates that you can convert (Similar to C#'s) `A.B(C)` to simply `D()` (D is the delegate variable).

My solution: To create those dynamically I thought about generating function in runtime and store them in the GCHeap (I need in the GCHeap because that it can be unreachable in the future), but to run them I need to make the whole memory in the GC marked as executable, writeable and readable.

Will it impact performance for accessing the memories that aren't delegates but still have been marked by those permissions? Is there better solution?

NOTE: I know those permissions is to throw exceptions when program doesn't working properly by executing memory that not meant to be executable, but I can't afford to lose the performance of big chunks's allocations.

Comment: No, flagging memory regions should not have any performance impact. It might have a security impact though.

Comment: There is no need to generate machine code at run time to implement delegates or anything of that sort. In fact, it's probably a bad idea from every perspective: Security aside, it's a lot of work, and a lot of very error-prone code, it requires more time and space, and it eats up that previous instruction cache (i.e. it might even be slower). You should research how other VMs implement first-class functions.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I guessed it, but still can't find good source.

Comment: @delnan Because of that I am open to other solutions. I know about method that the delegate is some struct and the `D()` is running normal method that invoking `A.B(C)` by reflection. But reflection is troubling me because is rhymes with low performance. I wanted the delegates to be more a function pointer than a struct (they have the information on them before the machine code) because it will make more performance.

Comment: @KugBuBu Where does reflection enter the picture? Just generate a specialized type/method for the call `A.B(C)` at compile time. And if you need a `A.B2(X, Y)` call elsewhere, then generate another type/method for that.

Comment: @delnan I need more features from delegates (that I can only do with generating it) but I can find a way out with this method. Can you write this as answer? There's no 'Accepted Comment' here unfortunately, and I am not willing to take credit.

Comment: There is a *major* security risk in making the whole heap executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of flagging memory regions that can do security issues. You can for example expand in compile time: (C# as pseudo-code)

```
public static Func<???> Method() { //Not the same Func as C#'s implementing, and ??? is the return type.
    MyClass A=...,C=...;
    return ( ) => A.B(C);
}
```

To:

```
class __call001 /* Anonymous type */ : Func<???> {
    MyClass var0, var1; //Storing those variables,
                        //because we won't have them available when calling the lambda.
    public __class001(MyClass var0, MyClass var1) {
        this.var0=var0;
        this.var1=var1;
    }
    public override ??? operator() {
        var0.B(var1);
    }
}

...

public static Func<???> Method() {
    MyClass A=..., C=...;
    return new __call001(A, C);
}
```